# Getting a password checker to recognize special characters in Python

Tags: python, special-characters

I'm struggling to get my password checker to recognize my special characters as true when they are inputted, any help would  be appreciated!

```
import re

def password_cri():
    while True:
        password = input("Please enter your password:")
        if len(password)<5 and len(password)>15:
            print("Password denied: must be between 5 and 15 characters long.")
        elif re.search('[0-9]',password) is None:
            print("Password denied: must contain a number between 0 and 9")
        elif re.search('[A-Z]',password) is None:
            print("Password denied: must contain a capital letter.")
        elif re.search('[a-z]',password) is None:
            print("Password denied: must contain a lowercase letter.")
        elif re.search('[!, @, #, $, %, &, (, ), -, _, [, ], {, }, ;, :, ", ., /, <, >, ?]', password) is None:
            print("Password denied: must contain a special character")          
        else:
            print("Your password has been accepted.")
            break    

password_cri()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'[!, @, #, $, %, &, (, ), -, _, [, ], {, }, ;, :, ", ., /, <, >, ?]'
```

is probably not the regex you're looking for. Try

```
'[!@#$%&()\-_[\]{};:"./<>?]'
```

and note that `-` and `]` are escaped because of how the `[]` regex block works.

Comment: This regex also doesn't contain all special characters you might want

Answer (score 0):

That's not the proper regular expression for matching those characters.

I wouldn't actually recommend using a regular expression for this, since your matches are only one character long. Instead, make a string containing all the special characters you want to match, and then use `any()` and `map()` to determine if any of the special characters appear in the password.

```py
password = "????????"
special_characters = '!@#$%&()-_[]{};:"./<>?'

if any(map(lambda x: x in password, special_characters)):
    print("Password contains special characters")
else:
    print("Password denied: must contain a special character")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put something together and thought I'd share what I came up with.

The approach that I took was to strip out the upper lower and digit character groups and assume that whatever is left-over is a symbol.

This isn't a good solution for non-american audiences, but I don't see a way in python's re module to specify foreign alphabetical characters (\w includes digits and the underscore. Also, I believe upper vs lower isn't a thing in some languages so not sure what to do about that.

```
def password_character_groups( password: str ) -> int:
    groups: int = 0
    pwd2 = re.sub( r'[A-Z]', '', password )
    if pwd2 != password:
        groups += 1
    pwd3 = re.sub( r'[a-z]', '', pwd2 )
    if pwd3 != pwd2:
        groups += 1
    pwd4 = re.sub( r'[0-9]', '', pwd3 )
    if pwd4 != pwd3:
        groups += 1
    if pwd4:
        groups += 1
    return groups
```

P.S. FWIW I prefer to do entropy calculations to check password strength, but this is what the customer wanted sadly.